# Large dataset processing via cloud computing

Tags: arcgis-10.0, large-datasets, cloud-gis

I need to process a large dataset.  Aside from processing locally on my computer, can I install, for instance, arcgis10 on a cloud service like amazon.  I don't have esri server, only arcgis10.

I'm not interested in storage or distribution, just processing.

I have ample bandwidth so upload/download isn't an issue.

Might seem like a silly question, but thought it was worth asking.

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS Server 10 (SP4) is on Amazon EC2 (Cloud Services)

http://aws.amazon.com/solutions/global-solution-providers/esri/

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_on_amazon_ec2/index.html#/What_is_ArcGIS_Server_on_Amazon_EC2/00rq00000002000000/

It has been available since July 2010

http://www.esri.com/news/releases/10_3qtr/server10-amazon.html

More info (PDF)
http://www.esri.com/library/brochures/pdfs/arcgis-server-functionality-matrix.pdf

Free 60 Day Trial
Evaluation of ArcGIS Server in Amazon EC2 You can request a 60-day evaluation license for Amazon EC2 running ArcGIS Server. Contact your local ESRI representative for details.

Comment: The cost of server is prohibitive.  But your last sentence may provide a short term solution....  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I wonder if there are any consulting firms that will let you run a process for a fee...

Comment: May be it is possible to install ArcGIS Desktop on any of your nonproduction servers? Especially if you have floating license. Or any rarely used workstation PC probably? Then you can leave it processing your data during weekend for example... I am trying just to understand the problem :) Can you clarify a little?

Comment: Sure.  I'm not a newbie to processing large data, I can get it done, I was interested if there was a better (faster/more stable) way.  I'm running a calculation on a raster dtm.  The main issue I have with processing it over a weeks time is the time cost of making  mistake or encountering a computer problem...

Comment: Have you considered to subdivide your data into several smaller parts? I have recently performed some processing with vector data and have discovered that processing of 1M features took ~15 min and the same processing of 500k features took ~3 min. Then I came to a solution of writing script for partitioning data before processing and collecting results after it (because actually I had to process 50M of data). Of course, I don't know if such solution is possible in your case... Anyway just some thoughts.

Comment: That is a good idea, and I did not know that data processed more quickly in partitions. It would work, but it would not be ideal.  The data is already partitioned, but since it is a raster and also because of the type of calculation I am making, I would induce "edge effects" into my calculations because cells near the edge would not "know" their neighbors.  I will keep your solution in mind though.  Do you have an email?